# bootstrap table collapsible child row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Can bootstrap table achieve following collapsible child row? below sample taken from datatables

[image]

Comment: its called an `Accordion`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Actually You Looking For An `Bootstrap Accordions`**

**Example Here:** http://getbootstrapadmin.com/remark/topbar/tables/footable.html

**Demo:** https://www.bootply.com/6ktNS2DIq8

Comment: but datatable able to hide the columns on the fly when I resize it. how to do that?

Comment: Yaa its Hide on datatable , & above example is based on datatable if you checked .. you can send me an codepen link.. where you try this